# using value of ng-checked inside ng-if conditions

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="radio">
   <label><input  type="radio" ng-model="tb3r4" value="0" ng-checked="true">Do not specify</label>
</div>
 <div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" ng-model="tb3r4" value="1">Yes</label>
   </div>
 <div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" ng-model="tb3r4" value="2">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now i am checking condition

```
<span ng-if="tb3r4==0">None specified</span>
```

**But** this condition is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ng-checked. Initialise you model value to 0. This should be done in your controller.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tb3r4 = 0;
});

<div class="radio">
   <label><input  type="radio" ng-model="tb3r4" value="0">Do not specify</label>
</div>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EXJqge1MKVuE2EAXKz5f?p=preview)

Comment: That's correct, but I would stay away from `ng-init` - this is recommended only to be used to alias variables in `ng-repeat`. Instead, the variable should be initialized in the controller.